# why is hashchange firing twice in Jquery Mobile backwards transitions?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, navigation, hashchange

I'm lost.... I'm trying to redirect Jquery Mobile transitions on **pagebeforechange** - as per the [JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

This should work for both forward and backward transitions. While it technically does I'm running into problems on backwards transitions. First one works, afterward for every back-btn click I'm getting 2+ backwards transitions.

I've ruled out the URL (now passing only full paths vs. paths and objects (like $('#page') ); That wasn't it. Now I'm looking for another culprit and can't find it.

Maybe someone else sees something or can give me a hint. Thanks for taking a look:

Brief setup with comments:

```
 // hashchange listener - just to see when hashchange fires
 $(window).on('hashchange', function(e, data){
     console.log("hashchange detected" );
     });

 // re-router
 $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {

       // block multiple events
       if(data.options.fromHashChange == true) {
           if(self.options.$blockMultiPbc == true) {
           console.log("blocked 1");
           self.options.$blockMultiPbc = false;
           return;
           }
        }

       // block $('#page') page-calls (triggered from trailing hashchange
       if(typeof data.toPage !== 'string') {
           console.log("blocked 2");
           return;
           }

        // redirect
       if(data.options.fromHashChange == true) {
            console.log("executing");
            // for hashchanges
            self.panelHash(e, data);
            } else {
                // for changepages
                self.panelTrans(e, data);
                } 
        });

       // panelHash function - here I reconfig data.options to redirect
       panelHash: function( e, data ) {

          // block multiple pagebeforechanges
          self.options.$blockMultiPbc = true;

          if ( some condition ) {
             console.log("MULTIVIEW");
             // tweak changepage options
             data.toPage = ...newULR (not $('object'))
             data.options.fromPage = ...new fromPage
             data.options.changeHash = true;
             data.options.reverse = true;
             console.log( newURL );
             } else {
                // JQM does this
                }
           }
```

Here is a sample page:  [sample](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/multiview/sample-listform.html)

To reprodude click *page2 menu*, *page3 menu*, clear the console, click browser back once, check the console (SINGLE RUN), click browser back again, check the console (TWO RUNS...)

**QUESTION**
I'm not looking for a solution - just some ideas on what might be causing the 2nd backwards transition to fire twice.

Thanks for some ideas!

**EDIT**
The more consoles I'm adding in the sript the more it becomes apparent, that the 2nd unwanted hashchange is coming after a short delay. I first thought it would be related to JQMs **fake_onhashchange** event, but removing this altogether did not do the trick. Keep on seaching.

**EDIT2** - found an [issue on Githu](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4094)b - so it's not my script... phew... Still hints are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think I found it. It's a bug in the pushstate handler.

Details and possible fix [on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4094)